Terraform - MSK - user permissions
My Kafka Client needs to authenticate with my MSK cluster through user / password.
I have followed terraform documentation to create and associate user. Now when I have a user, there are 2 things I am wondering about:

What is the set of permissions for this user?
How do I limit / edit the permissions of this user?


If you read the docs, have you seen this part: secret_string = jsonencode({ username = "user", password = "pass" })?

@MarkoE Yes but how does it answer my question? in this part I configure the user and the password. I am asking about the permissions that this user has in the cluster.

Ah, true, I misread the question.
